# Issues accessing GET variables in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Is there a way to retrieve the parameters in the URL inside your HTML page like you would normally use `$_GET` but in CodeIgniter?

For instance, if you were in the view and had the URL: http://www.mysite.com/controller/function/var1/var2

Then how would you be able to access what `var1` and `var2` were?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$var1 = $this->uri->segment(3);
$var2 = $this->uri->segment(4);
```

Read more [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html).

Answer (score 1):

you can also access it as if its a function.

for example:

```
public function somePage($var, $var2) {
    //get var
    echo "you can access ".$var." like this<br />";
    echo "or like this, ".$var2;
}
```

if you go to for example somesite.com/mypage/access/1/3

you'd get the following:

```
you can access 1 like this
or like this, 3
```

what Yan wrote is true as well, though know that you can do it like this too to save on typing.